# Get most frequent contexts between two words in word2vec

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I've already built my own Skip-Gram model by using gensim word2vec. I know that I can get the similarity score between two words, e.g. `model.wv.similarity('car', 'truck') -> 0.75`. Now I want to know why they are such "similars".

Since Skip-Gram has been trained with the context words, I suppose that there is a way to get the most frequent context words shared between `car` and `truck`. Another example: if I have the following sentences, I'd like to get the word `slow` as "most frequent context":

- `the car is slow`
- `the truck is slow`
- `the car is red`

Notice that `red` isn't appear with `truck`, so it shouldn't be returned as "most frequent context".

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The gensim `Word2Vec` model doesn't store all the text or co-occurrence statistics. The act of training is, essentially, forcing a model too small to remember all such co-occurrences to still perform as-well-as-possible when doing nearby-text-predictions.

So, there's no direct way to ask it "given N nearby words, what's the most common context word". Further, the point of training is to create word-vectors that happen to be useful in other ways, not to actually create the best nearby-word-predictor.  So, it's rare for the internal predictions of a `Word2Vec` model to be available via an interface method – the original word2vec.c code from Google, for example, didn't provide an interface for that.

There is an new, experimental method `predict_output_word()` in `gensim` that somewhat simulates an model prediction given some number of context words. However, it doesn't quite weight the context words the same as during training, and doesn't work in all model modes. Still, it might have useful outputs similar to your original goal, so check it out:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.predict_output_word

(If you truly need a precise report of which words are most often found within W spots of to N other words in your corpus, you'd have to use other, non-Word2Vec code to build the necessary co-occurrence lookup tables, or re-scan the corpus for each query.)

Answer (score 1):

With gensim you can get the N closest words to a given embedding. Why don't you try to get the average vector of "car" and "truck" ( [v(car) + v(truck)]/2 ) and then query the model for the closest words of this average vector ?